# check if input is empty then the default value will be send to the database

Tags: jquery

I have a form that have ability to set default value if the user will not input anything.

**form**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="pmi" name="pmi" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="birth_date" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="admission_date" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I want only the default value work if the input are empty. 
**jquery**

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function (){
            $(".pmi").val("0");
            $("input[name=birth_date]").val(d.yyyymmdd());
            $("input[name=admission_date]").val(d.yyyymmdd());

        });
```

Comment: You can do that on server side why you want this on client?

Comment: Your html seems invalid? you have `name="name="` where it should be just `name="`

Comment: thank you for the correction.. above code is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function () {
    if ($(".pmi").val() == "") {
        $(".pmi").val("0");
    }
    $("input[name=birth_date], input[name=admission_date]").val(function (i, val) {
        return val || d.yyyymmdd();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
!$(".pmi").val() && $(".pmi").val("0");
!$("input[name=birth_date]").val() && $("input[name=birth_date]").val(d.yyyymmdd());
!$("input[name=admission_date]").val() && $("input[name=admission_date]").val(d.yyyymmdd());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function (){
if($(".pmi").val()==""){            
   $(".pmi").val("0");
}
if($("input[name=birth_date]").val() == ""){
   $("input[name=birth_date]").val(d.yyyymmdd());
}
if($("input[name=admission_date]").val() == ""){
   $("input[name=admission_date]").val(d.yyyymmdd());
}
});
```